# Quick-delete surrounding statements in Visual Studio or Resharper

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

I often find I need to remove nesting statements, say an if conditional becomes irrelevant:

#### From

```
if (processFile != null && processFile.Exists)
{
    Process[] processesByName = GetProcesses(processFile.NameWithoutExt);
    if (processesByName.Length > 0)
    {
        return processesByName.ToList();
    }
}

return null;
```

#### To

```
Process[] processesByName = GetProcesses(processFile.NameWithoutExt);
if (processesByName.Length > 0)
{
    return processesByName.ToList();
}

return null;
```

The trouble is having to manually find the curly braces on both sides and delete them, while retaining the nested code

- Especially with larger bodies, unlike the example here
- Any way to quick-erase with Resharper?
- Or in Visual Studio natively?

Comment: I usually delete the if line manually, then position the cursor at the first curly and invoke "remove unnecessary curly braces" (alt+ enter, I believe)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Shift+delete` to cut `IF` line

`Alt+Enter` on bracket to remove redundant braces.

Comment: this sounds like the best solution thus far, but was thinking of a general solution for which it does not work e.g. to remove try .. catch or to remove if .. else .. (and i guess in the latter case the code inside else should be deleted as well)

Comment: Use ctrl+shift+] on starting bracket to select code inside it

Comment: `Alt`+`Enter` opens `Property` window for me (`Visual C# 2005` keyboard mapping, VS2013 Express). I am not sure if it's default, could you tell which command is executed by pressing `Alt`+`Enter` for you?

Comment: I have VS2010+Resharper+CodeMaid, when I'm on bracket I see hammer icon on left side of screen, hover cursor on it and check tool tip for shortcut.

Comment: `Alt+Enter` does not work in VS. Any idea how to make it work without ReSharper in VS 2017?

Answer (score 2):

Change the condition to `if (true || whatever)`? I think that ReSharper will then tell you that the condition is always true, and will offer to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, although it might not be ideal:

- Click and drag to mark the code you want to keep.
- Use the Resharper command *"Surround with..*." and select "`#region`".
- Now you can collapse the code you want to keep using the minus sign at the top of the new region.
- Remove the code surrounding the `#region`
- Now click the `#region` title again and select the Resharper option "*Remove region/endregion directives*".

Not a perfect solution, but it should help you get a better overview of what you're doing when working with larger blocks of code than your OP example.

It should look something like this (where the `#region` directive can hide any of lines of code):

[image]